# How to put parametrs in url with queryParamets in GET-request in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an API and I need to put non-optional parametrs in GET-request and I did this:

```
Future<List<FlightBook>> fetchFlights(int mv_id) async {
   
    String basicAuth =
        'Basic ' + base64Encode(utf8.encode('$username:$password'));
    print(basicAuth);

    final queryParameters = {
     "mv_id" : mv_id,
    };
    
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse("http:/mylink/getFlights.php?fmt=json&{$queryParameters}" ),  headers: <String, String>{'authorization': basicAuth});
    var jsonResponse = convert.jsonDecode(response.body) as List;
    return jsonResponse.map((e) => FlightBook.fromJson(e)).toList();
  }
```

but when I tried to get some data from this I got the blank screen with no values and after that I did request like so and everything works fine:

```
 'var response = await http.get(Uri.parse("http:/mylink/getFlights.php?fmt=json&mv_id=1'
```

How can I put this parametr inside my link if I need not only the first elemnt but all elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try out with this

```
 final queryParameters = {
     "mv_id" : mv_id,
     "fmt" : "json",
    };
    var uri = Uri(scheme: "http", host: "/mylink/getFlights.php", queryParameters:queryParameters );
    var response = await http.get(uri,  headers: <String, String>{'authorization': basicAuth});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your string interpolation is wrong.  The $ goes outside the braces.

You could do: `"http:/mylink/getFlights.php?fmt=json&${queryParameters}"`

But in this case, you don't need the curly braces, so I would do
`"http:/mylink/getFlights.php?fmt=json&$queryParameters"`

I agree with the other response on how to add the query parameters, but wanted to show why your version failed in one case and worked in the other.